# How to upgrade safely php version in wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver

I downloaded latest wamp server and I installed in my system with php version 5.5.12 and now I want to upgrade php version to 5.5.27 with safely.. How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 72):

**For someone who need to update the PHP version in WAMP**, I can recommend this http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/

I had a problems with updating too, but on this website are Wampserver addons like new php version (php 7.1.4 etc.) And you don't have to manually edit files like php.ini or phpForApache.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This solution is much easier to use.  Thanks!

Comment: Great stuff, thank you! I'm amazed that everywhere I looked this resource wasn't mentioned. I was spending hours trying to get this working the manual way.

Comment: What if I want to downgrade version of php?

Comment: Providing you have Wampserver 3.1.4 or later.  Addons not compatible for prior versions

Comment: I needed to upgrade the php to php ver. 7.4 in order to implement Opcache for Symfony application. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 39):

WAMP server generally provide addond for different php/mysql versions. However you mentioned you have downloaded latest wamp server. As of now, latest Wamp server v2.5 provide PHP version 5.5.12

So you need to upgrade it manually as follow:

1. Download binaries on php.net
2. Extract all files in a new folder : C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.27/
3. Copy the wampserver.conf from another php folder (like php/php5.5.12/) to the new folder
4. Rename php.ini-development file to phpForApache.ini
5. Done ! Restart WampServer (>Right Mouseclick on trayicon >Exit)

Although not asked, I'd recommend to vagrant/puppet or docker for local development. Check puphpet.com for details. It has slight learning curve but it will give you much better control of different versions of every tool.

Comment: You also need to create a `php.ini` file from `php.ini-development` (for PHP CLI) Then the important bit, go through both ini files and change any directory references to WAMPerise the ini files. As its 5.5.12 to 5.5.17 you can probably get away with copying the 5.5.12 ini files to the 5.5.17 folder. But these shoud also be checked/compared for any obvious differences. Remember a version upgrade may change ini file contents. **So have a care in this process**

Comment: Work perfectly!, Make sure you exit from wamp, do not try only restart wamp... Thanks :)

Comment: not working for me..

Comment: **Warning**, this answerwhile correct at the time, is well out of date. WAMPServer 3 now supplied ADDON installers for all versions of PHP/MySQL/mariaDB/phpMyAdmin/Apache.....

Answer (score 7):

1. Simply Download the PHP version that you want from this url: http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/
2. Goto your `wamp\bin\php` directory and extract it like this(Note: you need to rename your folder to php`versionOfPhp`
   [image: list of installed version in the directory]
3. Start wamp and click wamp icon and choose the version of php you want to use:
   https://gyazo.com/de5727d7e254795e238422783dec3758

Comment: You have to add php.ini , phpForApache.ini and wampserver.conf if you are using WAMP. from the old version then Search for any references to your old PHP version and replace them with the new PHP version.

Comment: It's not about replacing the version but adding support for multiple versions of php in wamp server. This method worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Use sourceforge or [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) to download the official ADDON's and it will work without all this hassle

Answer (score 4):

To add to the above answer (do steps 1-5).

1. Click on WAMP -> Select PHP -> Versions: Select the new version installed
2. Check that your PATH folder is updated to new path to PHP so your OS has same PHP version of WAMP.

Answer (score 3):

One important step is missing in all answers. I successfully upgraded with following steps:

- stop apache service with wamp stack manager.
- rename your wampstack/php dir to wampstack/php_old
- copy new php dir to wampstack/
- replace wampstack/php/php.ini by wampstack/php_old/php.ini
- test and fix any error with php -v (for example missing extensions)
- [optional] update php version in wampstack/properties.ini
- Replace wampstack/apache/bin/php7ts.dll by wampstack/php/php7ts.dll

  - This is not mentioned in the other answers but you need this to use
    the right php version in apache!
- start apache service

Comment: This worked! On the php -v step for reference I had to install mongodb.dll from http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.5.1/windows. I also copied libsasl.dll from php to apache/bin based on other instructions. Not sure if it was necessary.

Comment: I had to copy php/tmp from the old to new for phpmyadmin to load.

Comment: Use sourceforge or [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) to download the official ADDON's and it will work without all this hassle