# Install new php version in wamp for magento

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I had faced two problems with Wamp.

1) I cannot upgrade the php version. I tried a recommended way https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/ , but it didn't work.

2) I cannot change the php version from 5.6.16 to 7.0.0 (the default versions of wamp)

These problems showed up when I added a Magento framework in my wamp server. The only version which accepted for Magento setup are 5.6.5, 7.0.2, 7.0.4, 7.0.6

What Can I do?

Comment: Have you tried with XAMPP? for Magento 2 i am using it and it is working fine.

Comment: No I didn't. Now I see there are these versions in xampp! But if there is a way for wamp I need to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a version of WAMPServer > 3.0 then there are lots of simple php ADDON installs that you can pick from

See [SourceForge repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Php/) for all the available PHP ADDONS

Or the [backup Repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) which can be easier to navigate than SourceForge.

These are simply download and run the installs. It will just add another PHP folder in the usual place in the `wamp` folder structure.

You can then Switch to the new release and back again to older releases using the wampmanager menus.

Note: There are also many versions of Apache, MySQL and mariaDB as well.

And if you upgrade to WAMPServer 3.0.8 (again a simple download and click the install), you can also add MariaDB installs as well.

Answer (score 13):

Via [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804864/how-to-upgrade-safely-php-version-in-wamp-server)

1. Download binaries on php.net (ZIP package based on your PC bit That package should php.exe file)
2. Extract all files in a new folder :C:/wamp/bin/php/php(7.0.0)/
3. Copy the wampserver.conf from another php folder (like php/php5.6.16/) to the new folder
4. Rename php.ini-development file to phpForApache.ini
5. Restart WampServer

Comment: Which php binary? thread safe
32 or 64 depends on your wamp, Open task manager and look if 32 appears after wampserver exe. If not x64.

Comment: Note that php7apache2_4.dll may not ship with the nts release (e.g. php7.4.9), but does with the TS release. Also, php7.4.9 may not work with earlier versions of WAMP.