# How do you switch between PHP versions in Wamp 3?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

In the old wampserver I remember there was a versions tab that allowed you to switch between multiple versions of php.  Like this:

[image: Old Wamp Server PHP Versions Tab]

But now in wampserver 3 I don't see that tab anywhere.  There's only a wamp settings and a t tools tab - as seen here:

[image: Wampserver3 Settings Tab]

and Here:

[image: Wampserver3 Tools Tab]

Does anyone know where to switch between the different PHP version on wampserver 3?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804864/how-to-upgrade-safely-php-version-in-wamp-server

Comment: **LEFT CLICK** the WAMPServer icon, not right click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Left-click on wamp icon -> PHP -> Versions. 
You are right-clicking instead which opens different menu.

Comment: wow.. No matter, how many times i right click, i cant get this menu out. hehe.. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Can't believe I had to Google this one up :) Thanks.