# WampServer doesn't update the PHP version list

Tags: php, wampserver

as the title above, WampServer seems like doesn't update the PHP version list....

I already download and include `php7.4.10` folder, but the list doesn't seems to be updated....

I also even restart my computer, and the list didn't updated..

[image]
[image]

For your info, this is on production server...

While in test server and my localhost, there's nothing problem at all to upgrade the php version...

This problem occurred only to my production server..

Is there any alternative way to update the php version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade safely php version in wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804864/how-to-upgrade-safely-php-version-in-wamp-server)

Comment: @WesleySmith , nope.... i already follow the step.... but the wampserver settings (in tray icon) doesn't update the php version list

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658155/1376624, it points to this link https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/, on that page they have a 32 bit or 64 bit version of an exe file for php 7.4. Ive not used it but presumably that exe will automatically and properly install php 7.4 on your existing wamp server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it !
Add the following in line 2 of the wamp64/scripts/refresh.php file :

```html
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

It will just avoid a memory exceed issue aborting wamp manager update.
Then restart wampmanager :)

Comment: i have this problem once again when upgrade to php 8.... and your answer save me, right on time..... thank you so much...

Comment: You're welcome, I lost a valuable hour on this, I looked into the php log to find the issue :)

Comment: This was the correct solution. Don't forget to refresh wamp and restart all services.

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue today when updating to PHP 8.0.3, where after installing the add-on for the new version from https://wampserver.aviatechno.ne, the new 8.0.3 version wasn't added to the list at WAMP>PHP>Versions.

The solution that worked for me:

1. Check if there is a PHP error (that happens when you Refresh WAMP) by going to WAMP>PHP>PHP Error Log.
2. I found an error where PHP didn't have enough memory to Refresh WAMP.
3. I increased the memory_limit in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\php.ini to 2000M from 128M (Note: if WAMP uses a different PHP version for CLI, update their respective php.ini)
4. Right-click WAMP > Refresh

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This corrected my issue, thanks for this.

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much! I had the exact same issue. I also had to update the php.ini for the 5.6 version of PHP, even though I was currently using 7.3 and adding 7.4. Weird. Don't know why WAMP was looking at the .ini for such an old version, unless it uses the first php.ini file it finds in the bin/php directory.

Comment: @bansheekitty Thank you for your kind words. I'm glad you found this helpful. I think WAMP defaults to using PHP5.6 for it's CLI.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to  manually install `PHP 7.4.10`,into your WampServer version.

> 1. Download binaries on php.net
> 2. Extract all files in a new folder :C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.10/
> 3. Copy the wampserver.conf from another php folder (like php/php7.2.14/) to the new
>    folder
> 4. Rename php.ini-development file to phpForApache.ini
> 5. Done ! Restart WampServer.

This will help you.

Comment: Use sourceforge or [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) to download the official ADDON's and it will work without all this hassle

Comment: @RiggsFolly,, yes..i know that... But i need to configure the php.ini for performance... And the problem occurred because my mistake in configuring the php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Ok... now I know why... it is because there's something wrong in `php.ini` configuration.. need to check again the configuration..... for my case, I need to remove the code as image below:

[image]

Actually fresh `php version 7.4.10` doesn't have this `interbase` configuration.... i copy this `[interbase]` code from previous php version which is `version 7.2.14`..

But after remove back this interbase configuration, my problem solved..

Conclusion is: If you face same problem like me (or if apache service cannot started), it means there's something wrong with your `php.ini` configuration... trust me...

Comment: Use the provided WAMPServer ADDON's from sourceforge or [the backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) which is often updated first and is easier to navigate. From here you can download any version of PHP or Apache or MySQL or mariaDB with a simple download and click the installer. It will get things right

Comment: @RiggsFolly... Yes.. i know that, brother.... But for performance, I need to configure the php.ini... but for my case, there's some mistake in configuring the php.ini....that's all... Hope you understand...

Comment: @RiggsFolly... today I installed fresh wampserver and want to add latest php version... your comment helps me... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updating WAMP Manager Update 3.2.5 and Upgrading to PHP 7.4 via the Addons Package [both found here](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en). When I updated WAMP Manager it showed an even older version than I already had (on the GUI) and when I ran the PHP 7.4 package addon it did not show up in my PHP list.

My solution was to choose an even older version of PHP from the list and then after WAMP restarted my new PHP 7.4 was showing and the WAMP Manager was showing the newest version. So it clearly had to do with WAMP restarting which makes me wonder if restarting all services or a full PC reboot would have helped as well.