# PHP 7.3.30 extension not enabling

Tags: php, installation, php-extension

I was using php version of v7.0.0 which I upgraded it to version of 7.3.30 with getting help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804864/how-to-upgrade-safely-php-version-in-wamp-server#answer-31805119).

This is working fine except facing below issue -

- Getting PHP error as Message: Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt().

I tried -

- Uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file
- Also, uncommented it from phpForApache.ini file
- libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll was not present in installation folder. I have downloaded the latest version and placed inside `wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.30`
- Even though, openssl is enabled from ini, when I tried `print_r(get_loaded_extensions())`, I din't see openssl extension.

Still getting the same error.

I have also observed few things like -

My phpinfo() is showing -

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.30\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Any help to resolve this openssl_encrypt() issue is appreciated.

Comment: That answer is Well out of date. There are ADDON;s provided for each version of PHP from 7.0.0 to the currect 8.0.12 and the all live on either SourceForge, which I admit is a navigation nightmare. But there is also the backupo repo here [WampServer backup Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) Download the installer and simply click to install, then use the WAMPServer Menu's to swictch to the newly installed version

Comment: I suggest you UNDO all the above!! Simply delete the folder and undo any manual changes you made to config files

Comment: PHP7.3 does not come with `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll` because things have moved on. They are defunct. Opensll has moved to Version 1 and the names of the DLL's have changed

Comment: In the backup repo, you can also find upgrades to WAMPServer, upgrade to the latest version, it will only effect the wampserver code and not your sites/databases or the versions of PHP/Apache/Mysql etc

Comment: You should probably also look at the bottom of the Backup repo page and download all the MSVC C++ Runtime libraries, those too have changed quite a bit recently

Answer (score 0):

Got the cause of the issue.
After the php upgrade, I missed to update Environment Variable for PHP path.
I simply updated the Path variable with newer version of php from `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0` to `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.30`
This solves my problem. May be this will help someone.